# is there any way to add struts2 to myEclipse7 capabilities?

Tags: struts2, myeclipse

To make it more than 30 chars: I have myEclipse7 on my 32bit win vista. Is there any way to add struts2 to myEclipse7 capabilities?

Comment: i am not sure what you mean *add struts2 to myEclipse7 capabilities*

Comment: myEclipse7 in default mode supports struts 1.3!

Comment: you need to upgrade i guess you will get strtus2 capabilities in myeclipse 8.6

Comment: In netbeans there is a plugin for struts2, I don't know what that gets you... point being the easiest is to create a maven web project.  Same should go for myEclipse, that is you don't need any specific struts2 support from the IDE.

Comment: @Quaternion But it's really nice to have; I use it in IntelliJ.

Comment: @DaveNewton Can you elaborate a bit on why you like it.  I used to use a plugin for netbeans, but that was some time ago, they have recently updated it to support the current IDE but have not bothered. I'd like to hear what it provides... (I know you are using IntelliJ)... I'll post a question on the state of struts2 IDE framework plugins so people can provide what they know about each one.

Comment: @Quaternion I like context-sensitive autocomplete (result types, classes, whatever) in XML config, jumping between XML and Java, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have found on MyEclipse site about adding Struts2 capabilities.

- [Adding Struts 2 MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/htmlpages-func-display-pid-444.html)

More over MyEclipse is a paid IDE and i believe you can get best inputs even from there support system